# Set Space between imageview and two buttons in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have layout in which i have one `ImageView` and two `Buttons`.Now i want to set space between `imageView` and 2 `Buttons`.

**XML**

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/companyLogo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".1"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/clear"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right|center"
                android:gravity="right|center"
                android:text="Clear" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/add"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right|center"
                android:gravity="right|center"
                android:text="Apply" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

I tried by setting weight but it didn't worked for me.Please help me in this

Comment: Simply add some margin on the right and on the left of your ImageView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<View
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

Write this view in between ImgaeViews and Button.
It will work

Answer (score 1):

You can use [paddings](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#SizePaddingMargins), [margins](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#SizePaddingMargins) or instances of [Space](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Space.html) class in your layout to add some space between views. You didn't specify the desired result, so choose something that suits your needs.
BTW, `Space` is the better alternative for this task compared to `View` class because it was designed to be light-weight spacing widget and it doesn't make some computations that ordinary `View` does.

Answer (score 1):

try to add `android:layout_margin="20dp"` :

```
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/companyLogo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".1"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
```

you can add margin only for one side like that:

```
android:layout_marginTop="20dp" / 
android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/
android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" /
android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
```

[look here for more, ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams.html)